# Access VBA is it possible to pass items to the WRITE # procedure where the items aren't known until run time?

Tags: vba, ms-access, io

I am trying to write a process to output a .csv file from Access because The transfer to text wizard and DoCmd.TransferText apparently truncate my real number fields to two decimal places.

I have written a procedure to build a comma delimited string with double quotes around the text fields and then write line by line with Print #, but it would be cleaner to use Write #, which adds the delimiters and quotes. However it seems you have to specify each item in the output list with commas between. I would like to have a general subroutine that I can call with different lists.

I have tried passing an array but that gave an error. Is there any way to do this or do I need to stick with building strings with the appropriate quotes and commas for Print #?

Edit: The function I am trying to improve is:

```
Public Function WriteCsv(strFilePath As String, strSource As String)
'There is a bug in DoCmd.TransferText that truncates real numbers to 2 decimal places (as of 2021-06-01)
'This Function provides the functionality but may need improvements in efficiency

Dim i As Integer
Dim strOutput As String

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    
Dim intFileNum As Integer
    intFileNum = FreeFile   'Use next available file number
    
    Open strFilePath For Output As #intFileNum

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSource, dbOpenSnapshot)
    
    'Chr$(34) is double quote character
    
    'Write the header to csv
    For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 2
        strOutput = strOutput & Chr$(34) & rst.Fields(i).Name & Chr$(34) & ","
    Next i
    strOutput = strOutput & Chr$(34) & rst.Fields(i).Name & Chr$(34)  'don't want "," after last field
    Print #intFileNum, strOutput
    
    rst.MoveFirst
    
    'Write the data records to csv
    While Not rst.EOF
        strOutput = ""
        
        For i = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 2
            Select Case rst.Fields(i).Type
                Case dbText, dbDate, dbTime, dbBoolean, dbChar, dbLongBinary, dbMemo        'Use quotes
                    strOutput = strOutput & Chr$(34) & rst.Fields(i).Value & Chr$(34) & ","
                Case Else                                                                   'Don't use quotes
                    strOutput = strOutput & rst.Fields(i).Value & ","
            End Select
        Next i
            Select Case rst.Fields(i).Type
                Case dbText, dbDate, dbTime, dbBoolean, dbChar, dbLongBinary, dbMemo    'Use quotes
                    strOutput = strOutput & Chr$(34) & rst.Fields(i).Value & Chr$(34)   'don't want "," after last field
                Case Else                                                               'Don't use quotes
                    strOutput = strOutput & rst.Fields(i).Value
            End Select
        Print #intFileNum, strOutput
        rst.MoveNext
    Wend
    
    Close #intFileNum    'Close rst
    rst.Close 'Close the recordset
    Set rst = Nothing 'Clean up
    MsgBox "File downloaded to " & strFilePath

End Function
```

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Also show your current code. Are you pulling data from a recordset? Could maybe loop recordset fields based on recordset field count.

Comment: I stick with building strings with the appropriate quotes and commas. It's not that difficult.

Comment: The input is a recordset. Output is a comma separated .csv file with quotes around strings and a header